# insert xml tag with c#

Tags: c#, xml, insert, tags

I'm trying to insert a XML tag in an existing xml-file. To insert an XML-Tag in C# is not really a problem, but my Problem is, that i need the new beginning-tag and the ending-tag on a certain place in that file ... can anybody help me ...

here an Example:

this is the xml-file before:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <Item>
    <ItemID>2711</ItemID>
    <ItemTypeID>P</ItemTypeID>
    <ColorID>1</ColorID>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <ItemID>64566</ItemID>
    <ItemTypeID>P</ItemTypeID>
    <ColorID>3</ColorID>
  </Item>
</DocumentElement>
```

... this should be the new XML-file -> with the new tag "Inventory":

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <Inventory>  
  <Item>
    <ItemID>2711</ItemID>
    <ItemTypeID>P</ItemTypeID>
    <ColorID>1</ColorID>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <ItemID>64566</ItemID>
    <ItemTypeID>P</ItemTypeID>
    <ColorID>3</ColorID>
  </Item>
  </Inventory>
</DocumentElement>
```

can anybody help me?

Comment: It's probably easiest if you read the file, save the `Item` tags into a list, create a new XmlDocument, open an `Inventory` tag add the items in the list to the tag, close it and then save the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the existing `Item`s in a new `XElement` then replace the nodes on the original document:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<DocumentElement><Item><ItemID>2711</ItemID><ItemTypeID>P</ItemTypeID><ColorID>1</ColorID></Item><Item><ItemID>64566</ItemID><ItemTypeID>P</ItemTypeID><ColorID>3</ColorID></Item></DocumentElement>");
var items = doc.Descendants("Item");
XElement inventory = new XElement("Inventory");
inventory.Add(items);
doc.Root.ReplaceNodes(inventory);
//now you can save the XDocument to a file or whatever
```

Creates this:

```
<DocumentElement>
  <Inventory>
    <Item>
      <ItemID>2711</ItemID>
      <ItemTypeID>P</ItemTypeID>
      <ColorID>1</ColorID>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <ItemID>64566</ItemID>
      <ItemTypeID>P</ItemTypeID>
      <ColorID>3</ColorID>
    </Item>
  </Inventory>
</DocumentElement>
```

If you have LINQPad you can run this script: http://share.linqpad.net/7c636x.linq

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(file);
                var characters = doc.Descendants("DocumentElement").FirstOrDefault();
                if (characters != null)
                {
                    XElement xe = new XElement("Inventory");
                    characters.Add(xe);
                    var oColl = doc.Descendants("Item");
                    xe.Add(oColl);                   
                }
                doc.Save(file);
```